# removing a card from an array in c

Tags: c

So I made a program where it assigns each card from a deck of cards into an array. I was required to make a shuffle function, displayCard function, and also a dealCard function. What I'm really confused on is the `dealCard` function. I don't get the concept of dealing/ take a card from the deck and no longer having it into `deck[]`.

Comment: Perhaps you could pop a card value out of the deck...

Comment: After dealing a card, your deck will have 51 cards in it, not 52. So you need a variable that keeps track of how many cards are actually in the deck. This is different to `SIZE`, which is that maximum number of cards that could be in the deck at once.

Comment: @5135: Please look at the wikipedia page for [Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). Your shuffle is biased at the moment. The page explains how and why.

Comment: Proper prototype for shuffle: `void shuffle(char* deck, size_t n)`

Comment: so if it's shuffled in `main` already is there a way I can use pointer to the `deck[]` array and then after just shifting it from `deck[0] to deck[51]` to `deck[1] to deck[51]`? I'm just imagining that but I still don't know where to start from there. I don't know how it would look like in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather then view the deck of cards as `char deck[SIZE]`, re-define the deck of cards as

```
char deck[SIZE];
int deck_count;
```

Or as a structure:

```
typedef struct {
  char deck[SIZE];
  int n;
} stock;
```

Then create functions to manipulate the stock:

```
void stock_newdeck(stock *st);  // fresh deck of 52 cards: ordered
void stock_shuffle(stock *st);  // shuffle the n cards
int  stock_isempty(stock *st);  // any cards left?
char stock_draw(stock *st);     // draw the top card
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something the solution seems very simple to me.

One way to deal with cards that are not in the deck is to set the value for that card in `deck` to an out of range value.

The valid ranges for the values of items in `deck` are 0-51. As an example, define

```
// You can use any number that is not in the range 0-51
const char INVALID_CARD = -1;
```

When you remove a card from `deck`, assign the value of that card in the deck to be `INVALID_CARD`. When checking for existing cards deck, make sure you ignore the items whose value is `INVALID_CARD`.